# how to link two python scripts to a toggle button

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have two separate a python code on raspberry pi to switch on and switch off led. How to link  both python scripts to a single toggle button in python ??? Is is possible ???

Here is my code !!!

To switch on led i have python script **on.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.cleanup()
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(17,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(27,GPIO.OUT)
print "Lights on"
GPIO.output(17,GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.output(27,GPIO.HIGH)
```

To switch off the led i have a python script **off.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.cleanup()
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(17,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(27,GPIO.OUT)
print "Lights on"
GPIO.output(17,GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(27,GPIO.LOW)
```

Now i have created a toggle button in a python script **demo.py**

```
def page_lights(self):
    self.page = self.ui.new_ui_page(title="Lights ON / OFF", prev_text="Back", onprevclick=self.main_menu)
    self.list = self.page.add_list()
    self.list.add_item("Lights", chevron=False, toggle=True, ontoggle=functools.partial(self.ontoggle, "lights"))
    self.page.add_element("hr")
    self.title = self.page.add_textbox("Lights", "h1")
```

How do i link both my on and off python scripts to toggle button so that the LED turns on and off ???? i am trying to run demo.py on raspberry pi
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you make them functions instead of completely separate scripts?

Comment: `import on, off` but you will have to change codes in `on.py` and `off.py` into functions.